# USA Voltage versus Australian Voltage Question

Tags: voltage, relay

I am a complete novice to electronics and I have a very basic question - this being my 1st question!

I am in Australia and I am ordering electrical components to start my 1st build by following instructions written for the USA.

The suggested piece of equipment is this [Crydom 40-Amp Relay](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005T7VI46).

The voltage in Australia is 240 volts (now moving to 230 volts to match Europe) while the USA is 110 volts.

Should I be ordering a relay that is suited for Australia - such as this [240-volt Crydom 40-Amp Relay](https://au.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Crydom/D2440?qs=mNyg5qXQ%2FsewQ0iRdBGALA%3D%3D)?

Comment: That’s an expensive SSR. What are you switching?

Comment: Original:  CRYDOM - D1240 (series 1, 120VAC, 40A, ctrl 3-32VDC), for EU CRYDOM - D2440 (series 1, 240VAC, 40A, ctrl 4-32VDC). So, your choice is correct.

Comment: @Kartman this is the project I am commencing https://kylegabriel.com/projects/2015/04/mushroom-cultivation-revisited.html. I am new to electronics, so I thought that this was the standard cost. If you can suggest a cheaper option, let me know.

Comment: Working with such voltages is **really** dangerous. You as a novice should at all means search guidance by a professional or use a module that protects you from direct contact. Do you have a life insurance?

Comment: The typical home in the US has single phase 120/240 volts fed by basically a center tapped transformer with the center tap being the neutral. We bond the center tap to ground at the main disconnect only also at the source. Either relay link is ok. The voltage and current are your main concerns. If you are not experienced is this type of work get the advice and or help from somebody that is, we do not want to collect on your life insurance.

Comment: Sure. 120 V or 240 V can give you a shock. It can even be lethal. But that is not what you asked about. There are practices you can follow to make it reasonably safe. I am assuming you know how to follow those practices.

Comment: @Gil the OP is in Australia.

Comment: @mkeith I value my health and safety. So I will be having a professional electrician to certify my work and I will be taking all safety precautions. I will be using the electrician to confirm my work before connecting to the mains electricity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was good to ask.

Even though the picture says 240 VAC, the datasheet says max of 140 VAC.

https://www.sensata.com/sites/default/files/media/documents/2018-04-04/ourproducts_series-1-120-ac-panel-mount_datasheet.pdf

[image]

So you need to get a relay rated for 240 VAC. The one you linked to will probably work fine. The control voltage is compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Since we’re 240VAC, the current is halved when using heaters etc. Besides, the standard outlet is only 10A. A 16A relay would be only a couple of dollars vs a SSR at tens of dollars. The relay boards referred to are not suitable for use in Australia due to poor clearance.  The wiring standards are vastly different  here. I’d suggest you find an electrician that can assist you to modify the project so it is safe and legal. Or use ‘off the shelf’ device so you avoid having to touch mains wiring. Eg: hack wifi powerboards to get switched outlets.

Comment: Did I miss the reference to a relay board? Where was that? The OP seems to only be asking about the SSR.

Comment: @mkeith, true but there was a link to the project he was building which prompted my other suggestions.